# Varnish or other sealant for yellowtongue under carpet?

Tags: moisture, sealant, varnishing, particle-board

I live in a humid area and currently have wool carpet on yellowtongue. In really humid periods, the wool soaks up the moisture and even starts to get the particleboard underneath damp. It stinks and the legs of the wooden furniture start growing mould!

I'm going to replace the carpet with a nylon so that it is resistant to moisture. I feel like I would also like to put on a waterproof layer on the yellowtongue, but I'm confused as to what I should use. Most of the advice I can find online assumes that I am either leaving the yellowtongue bare, or laying wooden flooring or tiles over it.

What should I use to make the yellowtongue water resistant in such a way that it doesn't leave an odor and won't interfere with the laying of the carpet?

Comment: Is "yellowtongue" a species of wood? Is it a name for some sort of particle board product? Where does the particle board come into play here? If you're in a really humid environment, you may want to avoid particle board products entirely as they do _not_ do well once they've been wet or even damp.

Comment: STRUCTAflor® has unique colour-coded tongues to identify thickness; -Yellow Tongue - 19mm for joist centres up to 450mm -Red Tongue - 22mm for joist centres up to 600mm -Blue Tongue - 25mm heavy duty for joist centres up to 600mm https://www.architectureanddesign.com.au/suppliers/borg-manufacturing/structaflor-general-purpose - looks like the stuff they made shelves out of in the 70s; more glue than wood.

Answer (score 1):

Google *kills mold floor paint*.

Forget that it's 'wood' and needs varnish. It just a thing that needs to be sealed to make the gross go away. Any kind of paint that says it kills odors, or mold and mildew should work.

The advice you're finding online is assuming you're not puling up the carpet and saying *eww*...

You probably have a crawlspace that's in dire need of some ventilation and that's the root of the problem. But a coat of paint can at least help treat the symptoms.

Comment: Ideally it *is*, but honestly it doesn't even have to be: floor paint or exterior or mold and mildew... and unicorns. It just needs to be encapsulated with some latex.